# Deploying to tablet from visual studio 2015 "Target device's operating system version does not meet the application's minimum requirement..." error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have visual studio 2015 and created a C++ UWP application which builds correctly, but I am trying to deploy it on a windows 10 intel x64 based tablet.

I have the remote debugger setup correctly and I successfully deployed a sample C# application.
But when building and deploying the c++ application I get this error.

"Target device's operating system version does not meet the application's minimum requirement. Minimum required operating system is Windows 10.0"

The windows version on the intel x64 asus eee tablet is 10.0 (build 10240)

In visual studio project, the 'Target platform min. version' is 10.0.10240.0.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a C# UWP application, if you press "Remote Machine", you will be asked to setup the target machine, that is why it worked.

But in C++, it doesnot ask you and just assume you are trying to deploy locally I guess. I opened the project properties -> Debugging -> Machine Name to specify the target machine and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample C# Program may be too trivial to trigger the same error.

I suggest a more advanced 'Hello World' Program, a "This is who I am", followed by a "This is what I can do" Program is more likely to trigger the same error.

A suggestion for the first Program: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/ms724429(v=vs.60) - that will run and tell you what version of Windows you are running on.

If it refuses to run you have your Target set incorrectly. If it runs it should say the same version of Windows as is running on the Tablet. I suspect you will more likely hit the first error, otherwise the output might be useful.

For the next test I can not suggest specific examples but you need to write a few trivial Programs that will ensure that one of the Libraries you are using is Linked and works on the Target; I suspect you will find that some Library believes it needs a different version for your Target environment than what is available on your Host.

For a 'Brute Force Solution' (while you wait) install a Compiler on the Target and compile with Target and Host equal (do not cross compile), that will work (unless your Toolchain is broken).

You can also install an Emulator (for the Target Tablet) on your Host, needless to say it should work correctly.